# Property of derivative of sigmoid function - ex cs229

Tags: derivatives

The context is these notes ( https://see.stanford.edu/materials/aimlcs229/cs229-notes1.pdf ) page 17.

From here:

$\frac{1}{{(}{1}\hspace{0.33em}{+}\hspace{0.33em}{e}^{{-}{z}}{)}^{2}}\hspace{0.33em}\cdot\hspace{0.33em}{(}{e}^{{-}{z}}{)}$

To Here:

$\frac{1}{{(}{1}\hspace{0.33em}{+}\hspace{0.33em}{e}^{{-}{z}}{)}}\hspace{0.33em}\cdot\hspace{0.33em}\left({{1}{-}\hspace{0.33em}\frac{1}{{(}{1}\hspace{0.33em}{+}\hspace{0.33em}{e}^{{-}{z}}{)}}}\right)$

Bit confused about the negative:

${-}\hspace{0.33em}\frac{1}{{(}{1}\hspace{0.33em}{+}\hspace{0.33em}{e}^{{-}{z}}{)}}$

Can someone please help by filling in some of the intemediate steps....

Thanks

Comment: Thanks... do you mean rewriting the second expression as:
$\frac{1}{{(}{1}{+}{e}^{{-}{z}}{)}}\hspace{0.33em}\bullet\hspace{0.33em}\left({\frac{{(}{1}{+}{e}^{{-}{z}}{)}}{{(}{1}{+}{e}^{{-}{z}}{)}}\hspace{0.33em}{-}\hspace{0.33em}\frac{1}{{(}{1}{+}{e}^{{-}{z}}{)}}}\right)$

Comment: I think my question is a duplicate.   I have found something really helpful here:
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1115302/please-explain-the-algebra-in-the-last-part-of-derivative-of-the-sigmoid-functio?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Find common denominators in the parentheses. As a general rule, every mysterious algebraic simplification is made easier by common denominators.